# Is it possible to color every group of duplicate values in a unique color?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, duplicates

I have an excel sheet having in column C a large number of entries in which there are some that are duplicate values. 
I have this piece of code which basically go through the whole column C, checks for every group of duplicate values and colors them with a specific color.

```
Sub ColorCompanyDuplicates()

Worksheets("Master Filtered").Activate

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xChar As String
    Dim xCellPre As Range
    Dim xCIndex As Long
    Dim xCol As Collection
    Dim I As Long

    Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
    Set xRg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Filtered").Range("C4:C" & lastrow)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xCIndex = 2
    Set xCol = New Collection
    For Each xCell In xRg
      On Error Resume Next
      xCol.Add xCell, xCell.Text
      If Err.Number = 457 Then
        xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
        Set xCellPre = xCol(xCell.Text)
        If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
        xCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex
      ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
        MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

It is actually working in a sens that it is coloring the same values in column C with the same color.

However, my problem is that i actually want this code to colors every group of duplicate values with a **UNIQUE** color. My code is not doing it. It s repeating the same color for different groups of duplicate values.

Do you have an idea about how to modify this code in order to have a UNIQUE different color for every group of duplicate values in column C ?

Thank you :)

Comment: A *unique* color could be very similar to an existing color (e.g., compare `rgb(255,254,253)` to `rgb(256,255,254)`)... One thing that come to mind: using RGB and incrementing `rgb(x,y,z)` where you increment x, y, or z, dependently (0-256 for each).  Note that StackOverflow targets *objective* questions, which single answers, not a subjective answer or discussion.  As it stands, this question is viable for closing to being `Too Broad`.  Please update your post to be more objective.

Comment: Were you able to get this accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the colorIndex, rotate through the RGB values as suggested by Cyril in the comments.

```
if If xCellPre.Interior.Pattern = xlNone then xcell.interior.color = RGB((xCIndex * 159) Mod 256, (xCIndex * 68) Mod 256, (xCIndex * 47) Mod 256)
```

The values 159, 68, and 47 are going to give you a nice random-feeling walk through the colours so you don't get similar looking colours for a while. The `mod 256` part ensures that the values are within the allowed 0-255 range.

Comment: Thank you for you help @GregViers.
I changed this row "If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex" to this row "If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCell.Interior.Color = RGB((xCIndex * 159) Mod 256, (xCIndex * 68) Mod 256, (xCIndex * 47) Mod 256)"  but it is not coloring the cells anymore when i run the macro

Comment: Try changing the condition to `If xCellPre.Interior.Pattern = xlNone`

Comment: I tried doing this but nothing changed. The cells are not being filled in the different colors. @GregViers